# PKCanvasView shape recognition

Tags: swift, pencilkit

How to add shapeRecognition to `PKCanvasView`? looks like the SDK doesn't support that, are there alternatives?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PencilKit does support that, but it's private API. Only Apple's app can use it.
My suggestion would be: Check last stroke in the canvasViewDrawingDidChange(), then check with your algorithmen which shape it is, then create a beautiful PKStroke and replace the last stroke.